# OAuth 2.0 - Authorization code flow - Security concerns

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, client, token

I have some concerns regarding the Authorization Code Flow in the OAuth 2 standard.

Is the client secret used only to authorize the access of an API Client to a user resources or is it used to sign the access tokens, aswell ? Because if it is used to sign access tokens, it means if
one of my API consumers (clients) expose their client secret in their front-end, doesn't it mean someone could come and sign access tokens in the behalf of other users, eventually being able to access
those users resources ?

My first guess is that client_secret is used only for authorization and the access tokens are signed with another client jwt_secret which is stored and never leaves the oauth backend, is that correct ?

I am concerned about the situations when an API consumer leaks client_secret, authorization codes or other sensitive data, or maybe he even has bad intentions in using the user authorization to delete his resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [RFC 6749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749) might clarify your confusion regarding OAuth 2.0. Nonetheless, let's address your concerns.

> Is the client secret used only to authorize the access of an API Client to a user resources or is it used to sign the access tokens, aswell ?

Neither, the *client secret* is used by the ***client*** to [authenticate itself](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-10.1) to the ***authorization server (AS)***. Remember to obtain an [authorization code grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1) The following has to happen

1. The client initiates the OAuth 2.0 flow with an authorization request to the Authorization Server (AS).
2. If authorized by the user, the AS redirects to the client, appending an authorization code in the URL query parameter.
3. The client *exchanges* this authorization code for an access token by making a token request to the AS.

In **Step 3**, the client is required to authenticate itself to the AS using a client secret. This ensures that even if an unauthorized entity intercepts the authorization code (e.g., from Nginx logs), it cannot exchange it for an access token without the client secret.

So if a client leaks its own client secret, it's only compromising itself, not the AS. If we assume bad intentions anyway, a malicious client would simply use the access tokens granted to it, there won't be any need for any sort of hacking!

> My first guess is that client_secret is used only for authorization and the access tokens are signed with another client jwt_secret which is stored and never leaves the oauth backend, is that correct ?

The access tokens granted to the clients by the AS neither have to be JWT nor have to be signed. the OAuth 2.0 framework doesn't specify a token format. OAuth 2.0 implementations such as [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/creating-an-oauth-app) use opaque strings as access tokens (i.e. random sequence of characters). When using JWTs however, the access token must be signed. It is signed using the secret key(s) of the AS. Neither the client nor the resource server have access to these. The resource server however can use the AS's public key to verify the token. The [JSON Web Key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) set of the AS is public to everyone. This means that while tokens can technically be issued by anyone, only tokens issued and signed by the Authorization Server's (AS) private key are considered valid. Anyone can verify the validity of these tokens using the AS's public key.

> I am concerned about the situations when an API consumer leaks client_secret, authorization codes or other sensitive data, or maybe he even has bad intentions in using the user authorization to delete his resources.

If you granted a malicious client delete access to your resources, then it can very well delete them (without having to leak anything). This is why you should only grant access to clients you trust.